# Override + operator in python for float + obj

Tags: python

I have a class Vec3D (see http://pastebin.com/9Y7YbCZq)

Currently, I allow Vec3D(1,0,0) + 1.2 but I'm wondering how I should proceed to overload the + operator in such a way that I get the following output:

```
>>> 3.3 + Vec3D(1,0,0)
[4.3, 3.3 , 3.3]
```

Code is not required, but just a hint in which direction I should look. Something general will be more useful than a specific implementation as I need to implement the same thing for multiplication, subtraction etc.

Comment: I didn't see the "Something general will be more useful than a specific implementation as I need to implement the same thing for multiplication, subtraction etc." part but the link in my answer will take you to the [list of magic methods used to emulate a numeric type](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

Comment: It's okay, I stopped reading after "You're looking for __radd__" and clicked on the link :)
However, your code did make it a lot clearer, so thanks

Comment: If you have a custom __add__() for your class, then right after its definition you could just include a line `__radd__ = __add__`.  This works because radd swaps the argument order for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're looking for [`__radd__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__):

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __radd__(self, other):
        print other, "radd", self.value
        return self.value + other


my = MyClass(1)

print 1 + my
# 1 radd 1
# 2
```

If the object on the left of the addition doesn't support adding the object on the right, the object on the right is checked for the `__radd__` magic method.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `__add__` (and possibly `__radd__` and `__iadd__`) methods. Check out http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__ for more details.

Comment: If you look at his question and the code he linked he's already using `__add__`.

Answer (score 3):

implement `__radd__` . When you call `3.3 + Vec3D(1,0,0)`, as long as float doesn't have method `__add__(y)` with y being Vec3D, your reflected version `__radd__` will be called.